# How to push textbox value into Array and recall it

Tags: actionscript-3

*This is the first time I ask in this website, if there's any mistake and inappropriate thing apologize in advance*

I was trying to make my own basketball score board using Action Script 3 but I am stuck on the way of calling a player fouls score and show it individually.

In the picture, the second box is where to type a player number who made a foul and the third box is where the number shows how many times this player has fouled.
[image: The second box is where to type a player number who made foul and the third box is where the number shows how many times this player fouls.]

I need to know  how to code an array store that receives a value from the 'Player' textbox as the player number and stores the fouls count with the specific player's number too (if I type another player number it will count a foul separately and next time I type the exist number it will call out how many times he fouls)

Comment: You can push your textfield to an array like any other object : `array.push(textfield);` ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array, or a dictionary, or even dynamic properties.

Let's assume your text fields are called `txtTeam1fouls`, `txtPlayer`, `txtFouls`, `txtTeam2fouls`.  Let's also say you have a var called `curTeam` that stores an integer identifier for the team whose player number you enter (for this example, either `1`, or `2`).

Here is an example of storing a basic object in an Array:

```
var fouls:Array = []; //create a new empty array

//add a listener for when you type something into the player text input
txtPlayer.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, updatePlayer);

//this function retries a foul record from the array for a specific player
function getFouls(player:int, teamId:int):Object {
    //loop through the array until you find a match
    for(var i:int=0;i<fouls.length;i++){
        if(fouls[i].player === player && fouls[i].team === teamId){
            return fouls[i];
        }
    }
    //if no record in the array, return 0
    return null;
}

//this function updates the foul text field when you change the what's in the player text field
function updatePlayer(e:Event):void {
    var foulRecord = getFouls(int(txtPlayer.text), curTeam); 
    //if a foul record exists, use it's foul count, if not use 0
    txtFouls.text = foulRecord ? foulRecord.fouls.toString() : 0;
}

//call this function whenever you add a new foul record. 
function addFoul(player:int, teamId:int):void {

    //first, see if there is an existing foul record in the array
    var foulObj:Object = getFouls(player, teamId);

    if(!foulObj){
        //if there was no record, create one, then push (add) it to the array
        foulObj = {team: teamId, player: player, fouls: 1};
        fouls.push(foulObj);
    }else{
        //if there is an existing record, increment it.
        foulObj.fouls++;
    }

    //now update the totals for each team
    var team1Ctr:int = 0;
    var team2Ctr:int = 0;

    for(var i:int=0;i<fouls.length;i++){
        switch(fouls[i].team){
            case 1:
                team1Ctr++;
                break;

            case 2:
                team2Ctr++;
                break;
        }
    }

    txtTeam1Fouls.text = team1Ctr.toString();
    txtTeam2Fouls.text = team2Ctr.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise sir.